# How to use array values to query mysql/mariadb

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, hierarchical-data

```
I have a mysql table named tbl_member with the following datas
--------------------------------------------------------
mem_id      fullname    username    refrl   
--------------------------------------------------------
1       testing     jerry01     0   
--------------------------------------------------------    
2       ebenezer    ebenezery4  1
---------------------------------------------------------
3       aminat      aminat      1
---------------------------------------------------------
4       olaniyi     ebobofinger 2
---------------------------------------------------------
5       restoration restor      2
---------------------------------------------------------
6       adeyinka    cmaster     3
---------------------------------------------------------
7       aledo       akat02      3
---------------------------------------------------------   
8       friday      frayo       4
---------------------------------------------------------
9       ajoke       ajoks       4
---------------------------------------------------------
10      femi        lordfex     5   
---------------------------------------------------------
```

what i want my first query to do is get the mem_id from the tbl_member where the the refrl is 1 which means i wanted to get the list of member that are referred by jerry01

//here is my query first query
       $bestid =1;

```
    $query_frst = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE refrl = :sess_id";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($query_frst);
    $stmt->bindValue(":sess_id", $bestid);
    $stmt->execute();                                                   
    $r = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($r>0){
    while ($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                    $id = $r['mem_id'];             
                    //$N = count($id);
                    //for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++);
                    //echo $N;
                    echo $id;

                                }
            }
```

The $id will return the values 2,3
That is ebenezery4 and aminat were referred by jerry01

```
which are:
--------------------------------------------------------
mem_id      fullname    username    refrl   
--------------------------------------------------------    
2          ebenezer    ebenezery4   1
---------------------------------------------------------
3         aminat        aminat      1
---------------------------------------------------------
```

now what i wanted to do is i want to query my tbl_member to look for datas where the refrl are 2,3 nd here is my query  that i used

```
    $queryy = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE refrl = :id";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($queryy);
    $stmt->bindValue(":sess_id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();                                                   
    $remi = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($remi>0){
            echo"<table class='table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter'>";
            echo"<thead>";
                echo"<tr>";
                echo"<th>Username</th>";
                echo"<th>Fullname</th>";
                echo"<th>Phone number</th>";
                echo"<th>Current Stage</th>";
                echo"<th>Level</th>";
                echo"</tr>";
                echo"</thead>";
                echo"<tbody>";
                   while ($row1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            extract($row1);
                 echo"<tr>"; 
                    echo"<td>{$username}</td>";
                    echo"<td>{$fullname}</td>";
                    echo"<td>{$phoneno}</td>";
                    echo"<td>{$stage}</td>";
                    echo"<td>{$level}</td>";
                    echo"</tr>";
                    echo"</tbody>";
                    }
                    echo"</table>";
                    }else{
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in' role='alert' >You do not have any purchased product.</div>";
                        } 


But my result return only the data of 3 which are the member referred by aminat alone

--------------------------------------------------------
mem_id      fullname    username    refrl   
--------------------------------------------------------
6       adeyinka    cmaster     3
---------------------------------------------------------
7       aledo       akat02      3
---------------------------------------------------------

instead of the values of 23 which should be


--------------------------------------------------------
mem_id      fullname    username    refrl   
--------------------------------------------------------
4       olaniyi     ebobofinger 2
---------------------------------------------------------
5       restoration restor      2
---------------------------------------------------------
6       adeyinka    cmaster     3
---------------------------------------------------------
7       aledo       akat02      3
---------------------------------------------------------

i have tried to look for a way to solve it with my little understanding of php but i could not
```

What i want to achieve with this is i

Comment: See then new tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

Because your consequently overwriting the variable so it will store the last value only i.e 3

change this line to this. store all the id in array

```
 $id[] = $r['mem_id'];
```

In next query use IN in where clause like this . using implode pass the all id in where IN clause like this .

```
    $queryy = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE refrl In (:id)";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($queryy);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id", implode(',',$id));
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the responce i tried your approach but the error i got is: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\mlmpro\mem\matrix.php on line 115

Comment: you need to initialise the $id is array like this $id=array(); while ($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  ... } @ebenezer

Comment: I tried that too but i got another error Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\mlmpro\mem\matrix.php on line 125 what i discover is that when i echo the the id it shows 23 without any comma like 2,3 so i tried this approach $id = array();
    
     while ($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
           
       $id[] = $r['mem_id'];
     
    but it only echo arrayarray when i tried to echo the id but can it be because am using mariadb